# Is there a way to do a conditional and multiple row by row operation along a sorted and grouped tibble?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, row, lag

I have a grouped tibble where several parameters have to be calculated from others assuming a function that gets its values from a previous row. I have tried to find answers that involve `lag`,  `mutate`, `case_when`, and `aggregate` but had no luck implementing these in the following  toy dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

df <- tibble(
  gr = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  t = rep((seq(1:3)),2),
  v1 = c(1,NA,NA,1.6,NA,NA),
  v2 = rnorm(6),
  v3 = c(-0.2,0.3,-0.6,-0.2,1,0.2)
  ) 

# These operations 
(df <- df %>% group_by(gr) %>%  arrange(t, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(R1=abs(v1-5*v2)) %>% 
  mutate(R2=abs(R1*v2)^(1/2)) %>% mutate(RI3=R1/R2)) 

# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   gr [2]
     gr     t    v1     v2    v3    R1    R2   RI3
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   1   -1.39   -0.2  7.94  3.32  2.39
2     1     2  NA   -0.279   0.3 NA    NA    NA   
3     1     3  NA   -0.133  -0.6 NA    NA    NA   
4     2     1   1.6  0.636  -0.2  1.58  1.00  1.58
5     2     2  NA   -0.284   1   NA    NA    NA   
6     2     3  NA   -2.66    0.2 NA    NA    NA
```

Now, what I would need to do is to
use `df$RI3[i-1]` as input for `df$v1[i]`

`if ia.na(df$v1[i]) is TRUE`  and subsequently calculate:

```
mutate(R1=abs(v1-5*v2))  %>%  mutate(R2=(R1^(1/2))) %>% mutate(RI3=R1/R2)
```

row-by-row in order to `fill` the gaps within the sorted and grouped dataset;

doing this one by one would look like this:

```
Rdf <-   df
Rdf$v1[2] <- df$RI3[1]
Rdf$v1[5] <- df$RI3[4]
Rdf <- Rdf %>%  mutate(R1=abs(v1-5*v2)) %>% 
  mutate(R2=abs(R1*v2)^(1/2)) %>% mutate(RI3=R1/R2) 
Rdf
Rdf$v1[3] <- Rdf$RI3[2]
Rdf$v1[6] <- Rdf$RI3[5]
Rdf <- Rdf %>%  mutate(R1=abs(v1-5*v2)) %>% 
  mutate(R2=abs(R1*v2)^(1/2)) %>% mutate(RI3=R1/R2) 
Rdf
```

and would result in:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   gr [2]
     gr     t    v1     v2    v3    R1    R2   RI3
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1  1    -1.39   -0.2  7.94 3.32   2.39
2     1     2  2.39 -0.279   0.3  3.79 1.03   3.68
3     1     3  3.68 -0.133  -0.6  4.35 0.762  5.71
4     2     1  1.6   0.636  -0.2  1.58 1.00   1.58
5     2     2  1.58 -0.284   1    3.00 0.923  3.25
6     2     3  3.25 -2.66    0.2 16.5  6.63   2.49
```

I guess a `for-loop` within an `if-condition` applied to a `nested df` would work.

Any advise implementing this would be great!

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  There are some values that are random.  Please use `set.seed`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I realized that there were some complex numbers appearing from my previous example and fixed this with a better toy scenario. Also added the expected outcome and ```set.seed```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a for loop. But I am not sure I start off with the same df given the seed. Hope it does what you need.

When I need to write for-loops that seem complicated, I use browser() to build it.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
  gr = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  t = rep((seq(1:3)),2),
  v1 = c(1,NA,NA,1.6,NA,NA),
  v2 = rnorm(6),
  v3 = c(-0.2,0.3,-0.6,-0.2,1,0.2)
) 

# Data prep
df <- df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%  
  arrange(t, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(R1=abs(v1-5*v2)) %>% 
  mutate(R2=abs(R1*v2)^(1/2)) %>% #
  mutate(RI3=R1/R2) %>%
  ungroup()

#going through df row by row
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    #browser()
    # run into problems with i == 1 for the lagged operation, hence made two cases
    if (i == 1) {
      df$v1[i] <- if_else(is.na(df$v1[i]), df$RI3[i], df$v1[i])
    } else {
      df$v1[i] <- if_else(is.na(df$v1[i]), df$RI3[i-1], df$v1[i])
    }
  
  # rowwise calculation
  df$R1[i] <- abs(df$v1[i]-5*df$v2[i])
  df$R2[i] <- abs(df$R1[i]*df$v2[i])^(1/2)
  df$RI3[i]=df$R1[i]/df$R2[i]
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, janderkran.
This works! 
I was wondering if there is a way to do this using mutate?